# WPF - local/cloud application data storage

Tags: c#, wpf, cloud, local, data-storage

I'm writing WPF application for my friend. This is the first time I'm using this technology (I spend most of my time in 3d area), so of course I'm encountering problem after a problem. I already grasped more or less the idea 
of UI controls and how they layout etc. The next logical step in my proceedings is to have the data stored... somewhere.

And here's the problem, how do WPF relates to data storage? Do I have to create some sort of mysql database/tables?
At this moment I would like to have the data stored locally on the computer where the application is installed, but maybe in future there will be a need
of backup it on the cloud. What's the best technical solution?

Comment: WPF has rich databinding capabilities but does not make any assumptions about where the data comes from. Your data layer/repository can be a sql database, no sql database, in memory objects, text file, xml file, config file, window registry, web service.. etc, etc.Find a simple MVVM tutorial, try something, then come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several database engines, but.. if you want to store data and skip the server installation id suggest to try out SQLite , which stores all of your data into .dll files locally into your project folder.

You can use the Nuget package manager to get the SQLite package requiered. And also theres a lot of information to get started with.

Comment: That's an interesting information. Will this approach be scalable when in future the project requires cloud storage of the locally stored data? Also I need a solution which will enable several users working on the same data, as for example in medical clinic when several doctors have an access to the same data (appointments, receipts etc) from their respective computers

Comment: Is not that scalable, its perfect for local apps storage, if you pretend to have multiple user working on the same database then you requiere a server. MySql is free and pretty user friendly.

Comment: That's a very useful information. So in order to have several users being able to make the db changes I should have one locally installed MySql server that can be accessed from different machines of the same network, do I understand correctly? And if the demand of storing the data on the cloud arise this approach will make it fairly easy to scale?

Comment: Exactly sir, read this it might help you, have fun!
http://www.novell.com/documentation/nw65/web_mysql_nw/data/aj5bj52.html